# Method invocation exception when using spring mvc test

Tags: java, spring-boot, testng, jmockit, spring-mvc-test

I have a `@RestController` defined for updating `Person` class as:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/person")
class PersonRestController {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonService mPersonService;

    @PostMapping("/update")
    public Person updatePerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        Optional<Person> personIfExists = mPersonService.findOneIfExists(person.id);
        if (!personIfExists.isPresent()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return mPersonService.update(personIfExists.get());
    }
}
```

For brevity, lets assume that there exists a `IPersonService` and its proper implementation. The implementation is marked with `@Service` and is on the spring boot component scan path. I am using `JMockit`, `TestNG` and `Spring MVC Test` frameworks for testing this controller. I am also using `GSON` for converting `Person` object to `JSON`. Here is my test method:

```
@Test
    public void testUpdateFileDetails() throws Exception {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.id = "P01";
        person.name = "SOME_PERSON_NAME";
        person.age = 99;

        new Expectations() {{
            mockedPersonService.findOneIfExists("P01");
            result = new IllegalArgumentException();
        }};

        String personJson = new Gson().toJson(person);

        mvc.perform(post("/api/person/update").content(personJson))
                .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
    }
```

When I run this test case, I keep getting following exception:

```
Missing 1 invocation to:
        com.mytestapplication.services.api.IPersonService#getFileDetails("P01")
        on mock instance: com.mytestapplication.services.api.$Impl_IPersonServcie@8c11eee

        Caused by: Missing invocations
        at com.mytestapplication.rest.api.PersonRestControllerTest$2.<init>(PersonRestControllerTest.java:<line_number>)
        at com.mytestapplication.rest.api.PersonRestControllerTest.testUpdatePerson(PersonRestControllerTest.java:<line_number>)
```

Here  refers to the line containing statement: `new Expectations() {{ ... }}`

Can you please help me in identifying the cause of this exception?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to provide mock for method call to

`mPersonService.update(personIfExists.get());`

which is return statement of your controller method.

Also I believe that method also has another method call to getFileDetails in the service.

So if provide mock for both these method calls, your test should work.

Comment: Ok. But in my answer I'm asking to mock the method calls for IPersonServive.. Try to provide mock for method calls mPersonService.update and personIfExist.get()